# Local variables inside a react component (automatically) getting assigned values they shouldn't have access to

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tauri

So i am making a Tauri app with React and i have a `<textarea>` element where the user can input some text and then that text gets processed by the function `readInputs`. The function basically returns an array of arrays for each line of the string where the embedded arrays are just each line of the string split by a separator. But what is happening is that when i create the empty `strings` array it gets initialized by something happening waaay further in the chain of functions and i have no idea how that happens or how to prevent it. Let me show you the code...

```ts
export function readInputs(inputString: string): string[][] {
  console.log("inputString: ", inputString);

  if (inputString == "") return [];
  let inputs = inputString.split("\n");

  console.log("split inputs: ", inputs);

  let strings: string[][] = [[]]; // this is where the weirdness happens

  console.log("strings created: ", strings)

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log("modifying strings: ", strings, "with", refactorString(inputs[i]))
    strings.push(refactorString(inputs[i]));
    console.log("result: ", strings)
  }
  console.log("read inputs: ", strings);
  return strings;
}

function refactorString(inputString: string): string[] {
  console.log("refactoring string: ", inputString);
  inputString.replaceAll(",", "");
  return inputString.split("-");
}
```

The output of the `readInputs` function is then being used to set a state variable called `constructs` which gets passed as a prop to a component that reads the passed variable and draws an svg based on it, but first it modifies the array a bit to correctly draw the svg.

where the `readInputs` gets called:

```ts
// called with the onChange function of textarea
function refreshInput(input: string) {
  console.log("Refreshed input: ", input);
  let newConstructs = readInputs(input);
  console.log("newConstructs: ", newConstructs);
  setConstructs(newConstructs);
}
```

where the `constructs` gets passed as a prop:

```js
// ... somewhere in the return of the component
<>
  <textarea
    placeholder="Type or paste into here..."
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={handleInputChange}/>
  <Constructs constructs={constructs}/>
</>
```

The `Constructs` component:

```ts
export default function Constructs({
  constructs,
}: ConstructsProps) {
  console.log("Construct drawer got: ", constructs, " constructs");
  let modConstructs = [...constructs];
  console.log("Creating modConstructs: ", modConstructs);
  console.log("Adding linkers to sides...")

 // This is where "lin15" is added to both sides of the arrays inside constructs
  modConstructs.forEach(construct => {
    console.log("adding lin15s")
    construct.unshift("lin15");
    construct.push("lin15");
  })
// ... rest of code
```

The baffling thing are the console logs made by this code. These are the logs i get when typing the single letter <kbd>N</kbd>:

[console-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfPSM.png)

```
App.tsx:57 Refreshed input:  N  
parser.ts:25 inputString:  N  
parser.ts:30 split inputs:  ['N']0: "N"length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)  
**parser.ts:33 strings created:  [Array(0)]0: (8) ['lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15']1: (9) ['lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'N', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15', 'lin15']length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)  
parser.ts:96 refactoring string:  N  
parser.ts:36 modifying strings:  [Array(0)] with ['N']  
parser.ts:96 refactoring string:  N  
parser.ts:38 result:  (2) [Array(0), Array(1)]  
parser.ts:40 read inputs:  (2) [Array(0), Array(1)]  
App.tsx:59 newConstructs:  (2) [Array(0), Array(1)]  
drawConstructs.tsx:16 Construct drawer got:  (2) [Array(0), Array(1)]  constructs  
drawConstructs.tsx:20 Creating modConstructs:  (2) [Array(0), Array(1)]  
drawConstructs.tsx:21 Adding linkers to sides...  
drawConstructs.tsx:23 adding lin15s
```

So basically i'm wondering how this can happen and what to do about it. I have no idea if i did something wrong, but just based on the console logs i thing it either has something to do with React or Tauri. I feel like i provided enough code to explain the problem, but still keep it readable. If you need more i will provide more.
Thanks for any help!!